# How to set two step tip power option when using windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

i am using mstsc (rdp) to connect my remote computer
i will forget i use remote computer then press power option like `shutdown,reboot` by mistake.
Could you tell me how to set two step tip like windows server?

Comment: What is a "two step tip"?

Answer (score 0):

By setting Group Policy Method to Enable Shutdown Event Tracker in Windows, we can add two step tip.

Local Computer (or Default Domain) Policy - Computer Configuration - Administrative Templates - System - Enable Shutdown Event Tracker